# How to join Array JavaScript if the element in array cannot defind until it is loaded

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have JavaScript code like this:

```
  var categorylength = k[E].category.length;
     var mm = k[E].category;                

   for(var nhi=0; nhi <= categorylength; nhi++ ){
         arraypostcate = mm[nhi].term;
         postcate = arraypostcate.join(",");
    }
   alert(postcate );
```

How can I get value of `postcate` is string of elements (arraypostcate ) are created from for.
But I do not know to to get that. I used `join()` but it is not right method.

Note: I cannot use directly : `postcate = k[E].category.join();` because the elements cannot be created 
if the for loop run for each element.

I want result like : `postcate = k[E].category.join();` but use with for loop.

Comment: I need to join element after each for loop. :(.

Comment: It's hard to entirely understand without seeing your data, but it seems like you just want to create a string from each `mm[nhi].term` value, and separated with a comma. To do it in a loop, create an empty Array before the loop `var my_array = [];`, then inside the loop do `my_array.push(mm[nhi].term);`, then after the loop do `alert(my_array.join(","));`

Comment: Hi @squint . Thank you for very nice method. Thank you so much. Please add your answer and I will mark yours best.

Answer (score 4):

I could not understand the question properly but seems like this is what you're trying to do:

var postcate = "";

var categorylength = k[E].category.length;
var mm = k[E].category;

```
               for(var nhi=0; nhi < categorylength; nhi++ ){
                     arraypostcate = mm[nhi].term;
                     if(nhi === categorylengh-1) postcate += arraypostcate;
                         else postcate += arraypostcate + ",";
                }
               alert(postcate);
```

does it work for you?

Comment: Hi jediKnight. It works but it has undefined elements. Thank you.